# scrollViewDidEndDragging not called in UITableview when data is less

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am using pagination to show manage multiple data. Pagination works on both sides top and bottom. For this, I am using below code to call API. But I have faced the issue when data is not greater then `tableView` height. In this case `scrollViewDidEndDragging` method not called. So please tell me how to solve this problem. below code is working fine when data is greater then `tableView` height.

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    if(scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView.superview).y > 0) {
        print("up")
        if workerInfo.count > 0 {
            let topVisibleIndexPath:IndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows![0]
            if topVisibleIndexPath.row == 0 && startCount != 0 && !isDataLoading {
                isDataLoading = true
                startCount = startCount - requiredCount
                self.callAPI(isCallFromPagination: true)
            }
         }
     }
     else {
         print("down")
         if workerInfo.count > 0 {
             let arrayOfVisibleItems = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.sorted()
             let lastIndexPath = arrayOfVisibleItems!.last
             //  print("Array: ", arrayOfVisibleItems)
             print("Last IndexPath: ", lastIndexPath as Any)
             if lastIndexPath?.row == workerInfo.count - 1 && !isDataLoading {
                 isDataLoading = true
                 startCount = startCount + requiredCount
                 self.callAPI(isCallFromPagination: true)
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you do it in cellForItem method ? If the indexPath is last reload the data.

Comment: I want to get data when user scrolls up or down

Comment: Yes I know, when you scroll down you will reach the last element of your tableView, there you can hit the API and reload the tableView with added data.

Comment: For pagination, a common practice is to load additional data using `willDisplayCellAt`.

Comment: @inokey But I want to get data from API in both cases

Comment: @gauravgupta I don't see any problem with that either. You have `indexPath` property of cell that will be shown it it's `0` you can load your top case, if it's `== dataSource.count`, you load your bottom case. I wouldn't recommend using scroll behavior for working with API requests. It's too unpredictable.

Comment: @inokey you did not understand my problem. My problem is when in tableview only 3 rows visible then scrollViewDidEndDragging method not called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Can you please check this properties.In my code its works perfectly.

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        print("Called")
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Support Pagination
extension TableViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {

    // Set Pagination Trigger before DataSoruce remaining 6 items display
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // Load More
        setupPaginationAt(indexPath)
    }



    // If we reached at the end, check again if anything to load
    func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let bottomEdge = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height
        if (bottomEdge >= scrollView.contentSize.height) {

            // We are at the end
            setupPaginationAt(nil)
        }
    }



    func setupPaginationAt(_ indexPath: IndexPath?) {

        // If any network calls on the way, we must leave - Declare a Bool variable and manipulate the value of it
        if isLoading {

            return
        }


        // Validation
        guard let _dataSource = YourDataSource else {

           print("DataSource found empty")
           return
        }



        // Config Pagination Call
        func execute() {

            // Get Current Pagination - Hope you have page index's from API
            if let currentPage = dataSource.pageIndex, let lastPage = dataSource.totalPages {

                if currentPage < lastPage {

                    let nextPage = currentPage + 1
                    loadData(at: nextPage)
                }
            }
        }


        // Check InBetween or End
        if let _indexPath = indexPath {

            if  _indexPath.row == _dataSource.count - 6 {

                execute()
            }
        } else {

            // Assume End
            execute()
        }
    }
}
```

This solution should work.

Comment: I want to get the latest data all time when the user scrolls up and scrolls down. Your solution work in the scroll down the case. But how to get data in scroll up the case.

Comment: You can apply the logic on scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating, by checking the current offset direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your `table view` `bounce` and `scrollview` bounce `True`. then scrollViewDidEndDragging method called

Comment: tableView.bounces = true
        scrollView.bounces = true
        // Are you talking about this?

Comment: Yes. you can do this from storyboard also. In table view you have option for `bounce on scroll`. If this is true then scrollViewDidEndDragging method called.

Comment: Not called when tableview only 3 rows visible

Comment: Please check screen shot which i uploaded.